# Need guidance to fit logistic distributions to compare performances in multiple events

Tags: r, fitting, curve-fitting, logistic-distribution

Ok, here's the thing. I'm trying to compare performances in different running events (i.e. all registered performances in each event from 1990 to 2023), to estimate equivalent performances. After having tossed this data around for quite a while now, I need guidance about how to proceed or I will lose the rest of my hair...

The same scoring formula will be applied to all events, with the general idea that equivalent scores are those that can be achieved by the same fraction of the population. Therefore, equivalent performances in different events could be measured as those with a cumulative probability of 0.5, to make it easy.

The general distributions are supposed to be logistic, with Gompertz distributions for the top performances, according to human performance modelling. But to fit the data to these distributions is easier said than done.

### Main challenges with the data

1. Fixed-time events are only registered if they are above an event-specific threshold and thus data is truncated.
2. Performances in fixed-distance events come from competitions with different cutoff times (and thus the left tail is thinner than it would have been without cutoff times).
3. Particularly in fixed-time events, spikes can be easily recognized at round performances. This also means that many athletes don't continue after having reached a round goal, even if there is time left.
4. And perhaps the main challenge is that data still is sparse, particularly at longer distances.

Here is an *example of six events, with all registered performances*.

[image]

And below are the *right tails of each event* (above the 0.95 quantile of registered performances)

[image]

### Constraints

It is assumed that all events follow a similar distribution. The y-intercept should therefore be the same. Similarly to [A mathematical model for scoring athletic performances](http://libjournals.unca.edu/OJS/index.php/mas/article/view/28), the curve under 0 would denote those not able to realize any performance, and its value could be set to 0.001 (CDF).

### Questions

1. How do I fit the logistic distributions for each event, with the constraint that the y-intercept of each should be at 0.001?
2. Which parameter(s) in the logistic regression should be fixed, assuming all events follow the same distribution? Shape?
3. To tune the estimated parameters, in order to fulfil the constraint of the y-intercept, how would I know how much to change the location and scale parameters?

I'm using R and have tried to fit data with `glogisfit` from the `glogis` package. Sorry for the long post and multiple questions. But basically, I would simply need input on how to proceed to fit the data to similar logistic distributions. Thanks!